# Replace all spaces in a string with +

Tags: string, replace, go

I have a string and I want to replace every space in this string with a + I tired this by using:

```
tw.Text = strings.Replace(tw.Text, " ", "+", 1)
```

But that didn't worked for me...any solutions?

For example the string could look like:

```
The answer of the universe is 42
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use [`strings.ReplaceAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ReplaceAll)

```
tw.Text = strings.ReplaceAll(tw.Text, " ", "+")
```

---

If you're using an older version of go (< 1.12), use [`strings.Replace`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace) with `-1` as limit (infinite)

```
tw.Text = strings.Replace(tw.Text, " ", "+", -1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Documentation on `strings.Replace()`: http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace

According to the documentation, the fourth integer parameter is the number of replacements. Your example would only replace the first space with a "+". You need to use a number less than 0 for it to not impose a limit:

```
tw.Text = strings.Replace(tw.Text, " ", "+", -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this in a query, the `QueryEscape` method provided by `net/url` is the best solution: https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryEscape

```
import "net/url"

tw.Text = url.QueryEscape(tw.Text)
```